react-native-video on android only loading when inview? How to fix?
I am currently playing react-native-video elements in a flatlist and streaming videos in there with HLS. On Ios everything works fine and the preloaded video just shows up and plays instantly but on android it does not shows a white screen first and then loads the video while in view, even though it is "generated" earlier in time
Tried to debug onload,etc. and on ios videoloaded/readyfordisplay appears before i scroll to the view in the flatlist and on android it only starts buffering when the video is in the actual viewfield
